# Error 500 API de Jellyfin [Crear password]

Tags: php, api

Estoy creando usuarios mediante la api de jellyfin, creo el usuario sin problemas sin embargo la contraseña no me la crea me genera el siguiente error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://3.139.7.97:8096/Users/1b4c/Password): Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error in C:\xampp\htdocs\usuarios\editar_cliente.php on line 83
> Error al establecer la contraseña del usuario en Jellyfin

Mi codigo es:

```
<?php
    // editar_cliente.php
    
    session_start();
    
    // Comprueba si el usuario está logueado
    if (!isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
      header('Location: ../index.php');
      exit();
    }
    
    // Comprueba si se envió la solicitud POST
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
      require('../config/bd.php');
    
      function consultaClientePorId($id) {
        global $conn; // Accede a la conexión de la base de datos, asumiendo que $conn es global
      
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE clienteID = $id";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
      
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
          // asumiendo que clienteID es una clave única, debería haber solo un registro que coincida
          return $result->fetch_assoc();
        } else {
          // maneja el caso en que no se encontró ningún cliente
          return null;
        }
      }
    
      
      $id = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
      $usuario = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['usuario']);
      $password = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
      $estado = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['Estado']);
    
      // Consulta los datos del cliente en la base de datos
      $cliente = consultaClientePorId($id);
    
      if ($estado == 'Activo' && $cliente['Estado'] != 'Activo') {
        // El estado ha cambiado a "Activo"
        // Aquí haces la llamada a la API de Jellyfin para crear el usuario
        $url = 'http://3.1.117.97:8096/Users/New';
    
        $data = [
            'Name' => $cliente['usuario'],
        ];
    
        $options = [
            'http' => [
                'header'  => "Content-type: application/json\r\nX-Emby-Authorization: MediaBrowser Client=\"Jellyfin Client\", Device=\"Device Name\", DeviceId=\"Device Id\", Version=\"1.0\", Token=\"993ab47785d5\"",
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'content' => json_encode($data)
            ]
        ];
    
        $context = stream_context_create($options);
        $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Error al crear el usuario en Jellyfin');
        }
    
        // Aquí toma el id del usuario recién creado
        $resultData = json_decode($result, true);
        $newUserId = $resultData['Id'];
    
        // Aquí haces la llamada a la API de Jellyfin para establecer la contraseña del usuario
    $passwordUrl = "http://3.139.7.97:8096/Users/$newUserId/Password";
    
    $passwordData = json_encode(['Id' => $newUserId, 'NewPw' => $password]);
    
    $passwordOptions = [
        'http' => [
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/json\r\nX-Emby-Authorization: MediaBrowser Client=\"Jellyfin Client\", Device=\"Device Name\", DeviceId=\"Device Id\", Version=\"1.0\", Token=\"99d77cc95247785d5\"",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => $passwordData
        ]
    ];
    
    
    $passwordContext = stream_context_create($passwordOptions);
    $passwordResult = file_get_contents($passwordUrl, false, $passwordContext);
    
    if ($passwordResult === FALSE) {
      die('Error al establecer la contraseña del usuario en Jellyfin: ' . $newUserId . $passwordData);
    
     
      }
    }
    
    
      // Crear la consulta SQL para actualizar el cliente
      $sql = "UPDATE clientes SET usuario = '$usuario', password = '$password', Estado = '$estado' WHERE clienteID = $id";
      
      // Ejecutar la consulta
      if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        // Redirige de vuelta al panel si la actualización fue exitosa
        header('Location: index.php');
      } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
      }
      
      $conn->close();
    }
    ?>
```

Les agradezco enserio sus ayudas!!!

Comment: Según la documentación, cuando [creas el usuario](https://api.jellyfin.org/#tag/User/operation/CreateUserByName) podes enviar el `Password`

Comment: El ChatGTP-4 me juraba que no era posible, que debian hacerse en peticiones diferentes. Tenias razón... Agregué:' Name' => $cliente['usuario'],
        'Password' => $cliente['password'] y funciona mas que perfecto! Muchas gracias.

Comment: Lo comentarios son temporales. Sería muy útil para futuros usuarios si pudieras responder a tu pregunta con el código que implementante. Al pasar un par de días vas a poder aceptar tu propia respuesta. Saludos!